# Tomcat dont read web.xml file

Tags: java, servlets

My structur is like

> - WebContent
>
>   - META-INF
>   - WEB-INF
>
>     - jsp
>
>       - index.jsp
>   - web.xml

And `web.xml` file is as simples as can be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.2//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_2.dtd">

<web-app>
  <display-name>servlets</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

But when I execute it using eclipse in browser i get `404 error`, but when I move index.jsp to root directory it works correct.

EDIT:
After changes

> jsp
>
> --index.jsp
>
> META-INF
>
> WEB-INF
>
> --web.xml

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.2//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_2.dtd">

<web-app>
  <display-name>servlets</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**SOLUTION**

I found out that my Tomcat server wasn't restarting when I was compiling. Now when tomcat restarts every time I compile servlet it works.

Thank you for your patient

Comment: web.xml should be in WEB-INF?

Comment: As per your directory structure, `index.jsp` is inside `webcontent\jsp\indiex.jsp` why are you using path `web-inf\jsp\index.jsp`?

Comment: After changes directory structure is not clear. format it aptly

Answer (score 3):

you can't access file inside WEB-INF directly , that is only possible by servlets not by you.

This directory(WEB-INF) contains all resources related to the application that are not in the document root of the application. This is where your web application deployment descriptor is located. Note that the WEB-INF directory is not part of the public document. No files contained in this directory can be served directly to a client.

Answer (score 2):

`web.xml` must be immediately inside `WEB-INF`( also not in a sub-directory of `WEB-INF`)

Also try changing this

`<welcome-file>WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>`

to

`<welcome-file>jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>`

UPDATE:

As per your new directory structure, your `<welcome-file>` tag should be:

`<welcome-file>jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>`

Comment: My project name is `servlets`

Comment: @abu, yours is working and his is not working, the reason is (refer to his new directory structure, he updated that). He has whole configuration hayway.. JSPS inside web-inf and web.xml inside webcontent.

Comment: @skowron-line please put that `web.xml`  immediately inside `WEB-INF` directory...

Comment: It is in `WEB-INF` directory

Comment: @Abu can You enter to chat ?

Comment: sorry I didn't see your comment. Are you still there.

Answer (score 0):

404 error comes when your URL is not proper.

Check if URL is proper. 
Based on your directory structure your URL should be some thing like this : **localhost:8080/jsp/index.jsp**

Also make sure that web.xml is inside WEB-INF directory.

Comment: `web.xml` is in `WEB-INF` directory but after executing from eclips it goes to `localhost:8080/servlets` url, not like you wrote

Answer (score 0):

Firstly

The `web.xml` should be inside `web-inf`

Secondly

the path to `index.jsp` is incorrect in your `web.xml`.

As per your directory structure, `index.jsp` is inside `webcontent\jsp\indiex.jsp` why are you using path `web-inf\jsp\index.jsp`

as per your `current` directory structure it should be `.\jsp\indiex.jsp`

UPDATE : OP has updated the directory structure.

you should not put jsps in WEB-INF, you should put jsps in webcontent and the `web.xml` in `WEB-INF`.
reorganize your directory structure. put the `web.xml` inside `web-inf` and `jsp` folder inside `webcontent` then inside `web.xml` put path to welcome jsp as `jsp\index.jsp`

Comment: Having noticed `jsp` is in my `WEB-INF` directory

Comment: @skowron-line , you should not put jsps in `WEB-INF` , you should put `jsps` in `webcontent` and the `web.xml` in `WEB-INF` 
reorganize your directory structure. put the `web.xml` inside `web-inf` and `jsp` folder inside `webcontent` then inside `web.xml` put path to welcome jsp as `jsp\index.jsp`

Comment: @skowron-line , I have updated my answer, to reflect the updates in your directory structure.

Comment: Still got `404` after moving files/folders like you wrote

Comment: @skowron-line can you give a brief description of your directory structure now and paste what entry you put inside web.xml?

Comment: @skowron-line with new configuration. what URL are you using to access resource?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19270/discussion-between-skowron-line-and-mukul-goel)